# Smart contract that recognizes Tweets made by each Twitter user

Tags: web3js, blockchain, contract-design, contract-invocation

Is there a way for a Solidity smart contract to interface with Twitter accounts or Twitter API to recognize the number of "relevantly tagged" tweets that account made? For example, an ERC-20 coin is rewarded to each Twitter user for tweeting about "#EventA" X amount of times

Comment: Of course it is. Start learning solidity and you will find out how to make it.

Comment: If you don't bother to read the basic documentation on a technology such ethereum what kind of answeres are you expecting? Can twitter accounts interact with bank accounts? That's the kind of question you are asking.

Comment: unbelievable. next